# D3 gradient rectangle, add points with text on stops

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

This code generates gradient rectangle, I want to add a points with some value on each stop, how can I do that? Maybe there's another way to create a gradient where it is easier to add those as axis?
I'm ok either way, I need a point, or a line on each stop, to denote that this is 20%, 40% etc.
Please help, thank you.

ps colors array in this shape for other purposes.

```
const colors = [
  {r: 80, g: 0, b: 0},
  {r: 229, g: 80, b: 57},
  {r: 250, g: 211, b: 144},
  {r: 184, g: 233, b: 148},
  {r: 130, g: 204, b: 221},
  {r: 106, g: 137, b: 204},
];        
// Add gradient line
let svgGradient = d3
  .select("[id=id]")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", 10)
let padding = 0;
let defs = svgGradient.append("defs");
let mainGradient = defs.append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'mainGradient');
mainGradient.selectAll("stop")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d, x) { return `${x*20}%`; })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return `rgb(${d.r}, ${d.g}, ${d.b})`; });
svgGradient.append('rect')
  .classed('filled', true)
  .attr('x', padding)
  .attr('y', padding)
  .attr('width', 250)
  .attr('height', 10);
```

Comment: Why are you appending a `<g>` and a `<text>` to the gradient's `<stop>`s?

Comment: It was a mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're creating a colorbar. Be careful with the width and height of the SVG, since they can easily crop the text away if you're not careful. When working with D3, always use the DEV tools to ensure that the elements are placed when you don't see them.

```js
const width = 200;
const svgHeight = 40;
const barHeight = 10;
const textHeight = 12;

const padding = 20;
const nTicks = 6; // 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100;

const colors = [
  {r: 80, g: 0, b: 0},
  {r: 229, g: 80, b: 57},
  {r: 250, g: 211, b: 144},
  {r: 184, g: 233, b: 148},
  {r: 130, g: 204, b: 221},
  {r: 106, g: 137, b: 204},
];        
// Add gradient line
let svgGradient = d3
  .select("[id=id]")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + 2*padding)
  .attr("height", svgHeight)
let defs = svgGradient.append("defs");
let mainGradient = defs.append('linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'mainGradient');
mainGradient.selectAll("stop")
  .data(colors)
  .enter().append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d, x) { return `${x*20}%`; })
  .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return `rgb(${d.r}, ${d.g}, ${d.b})`; });
svgGradient.append('rect')
  .classed('filled', true)
  .attr('x', padding)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', barHeight);

const tickFormat = d3.format(".0%");
const ticks = new Array(nTicks)
  .fill()
  .map(function(e, i) { return i / (nTicks - 1)});

const ticksContainer = svgGradient.append('g')
  .classed('ticks', true)
  .style('transform', 'translate(' + padding + 'px, ' + barHeight + 'px)');
ticksContainer
  .selectAll('text')
  .data(ticks)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .text(tickFormat)
  .attr('y', textHeight)
  .attr('x', function(d) { return width * d });
```

```css
.filled {
  fill: url("#mainGradient");
}

.ticks text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="id"></div>
```